# How to identify whether Google Script is launched as a Trigger or Manually?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

How can I identify in Google Script whether the script itself was triggered by some event or it was launched by someone?

Comment: `functionName(e) {if (e === null) {return;} //If e is null quit`  An "Event Object" gets passed to the function with triggers.  That's why it's standard practice to use a variable named `e`  If the variable to accept the event object is null, then the function was not called by an event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically that is possible. If you are using simple triggers you must not call the function from another function. In that case you simply use your function as let's say `onEdit(e)` and try to check the values of `e`. For example check what is the value of `e.source`. Simple triggers will generaly have that value. Review [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to see what event handlers you can look for.

With installable triggers it's easier. Let's say you have `function1(e)` which you set up a trigger for. You can now check if you have a value for `e.triggerUid`. You can also use that value to delete the trigger if you want!

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there's a way for the script to know that. The simple triggers you can use are listed here: [GAS-triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). But it's also possible to invoke those functions manually through the GAS editor GUI or a menu item which calls the function.